# How to evaluate $\int \cos^2x \ dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I am new to integration and I want to evaluate

$ \int \cos^2x \, dx $

**What I done**
Using simple chain rule,

$ \int(\cos x)^2 \\
= \int t^2 \,dt  \ (t = \cos x) \\
= \frac{t^3}{3} \ + C $

By substitution of $t = \cos(x)$ I got with answer.

Comment: $$dt \neq dx $$

Comment: @The Chaz 2.0 So what should be the correct thing?

Comment: [check out this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Examples)

Comment: @the chaz 2.0  I'm integrating with respect to $ t $ , so why I can't write there $ dt $ ?

Comment: Duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827183/how-to-integrate-cos2x

Comment: No. May be like that but not duplicate

Comment: @RaviPrakash You assume $t=\cos x$.So,$\frac{dt}{dx}=-\sin x\implies dt=-\sin x dx$...So,that's why $dt\neq dx$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [double angle formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) for cosine:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\cos(2x) & = & 2 \cos^2 (x) - 1 \\
\cos^2 (x) & = & \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos (2x) + 1\right)\\
\int \cos^2 x\ dx  & = & \frac{1}{2} \int \left(\cos(2x) + 1 \right) dx \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x) + x + C \right] \\
& = & \frac{1}{4}\sin(2x) + \frac{1}{2}x + C \end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 5):

Consider $$I=\int \cos^2(x)\,dx \qquad J=\int \sin^2(x)\,dx $$ So $$I+J =\int dx=x\tag 1$$ $$I-J =\int \left(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x) \right) dx=\int \cos(2x) \,dx=\frac 12 \sin(2x)\tag 2$$ Add both to get $$2I=x+\frac 12 \sin(2x)$$ $$I=\frac x2+\frac 14 \sin(2x)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint : Use the identity $\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1$

i.e. $$\cos^2 x=\frac{\cos 2x +1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use integration by parts:

$$ \int \cos^2x \, dx $$
$$=\int \cos x \cdot \cos x \, dx $$
$$=\int \cos x \,d(\sin x)$$
$$=\cos x \cdot \sin x -\int \sin x \, d(\cos x) $$
$$=\cos x \cdot \sin x +\int \sin^2 x \, dx $$

So

$$\int \cos^2x \, dx =\cos x \cdot \sin x +\int (1-  \cos^2 x) \, dx $$
$$=\cos x \cdot \sin x + x + C-\int \cos^2 x \, dx $$
Thus 
$$\int \cos^2 x \, dx = \frac{1}{2} (\cos x \cdot \sin x + x + C)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sin 2x + \frac{1}{2} x + C'$$

Answer (score 1):

This is very bad way.

Take $\sin x=t$, then $\cos x dx=dt$. Substitute and you get $$\int \sqrt{1-t^2}dt$$

If you know [**Integration by parts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), you can do next steps easily.

Comment: I don't know integration by parts

Comment: @RaviPrakash you started integration recently isn't!! You will learn Integration by parts very soon, you can solve it very easily in this process as soon as you know the method.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$ make it easy to evaluate.
$$\int \cos^2 x\,dx=\frac14\int(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}+2)\,dx=\frac14\Big(\sin(2x)+2x\Big)$$